# Autocomplete search for any word in the sentence

Tags: actionscript-3, autocomplete, flash-cs6

I'm using an autocomplete for my flash app. The autocomplete uses an external text file. 
When I'm typing the first word of the sentence, it display all the sentences that begins with this word.

Is it possible to display all sentence that have this word (and not just the begining of the sentence) ?

Exemple : 
I've got two phrases : "I'm going to school" and " I'm going to look for him".

I would like to be able to type "school" and that it displays the first sentence.

Do you know how I can do that ?
For now, I have to type "I'm going to s" in order to display the first sentence.

Here's my code :

```
urlLoader.load(new URLRequest("test.txt"));
            urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadComplete);
            inputField.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, suggest);

 function loadComplete(e:Event):void
        {
            suggestions = e.target.data.split(",");
        }

         function suggest(e:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            suggested = [];

            for (var i:int = 0; i < textfields.length; i++)
            {
                removeChild(textfields[i]);
            }

            textfields = [];

            for (var j:int = 0; j < suggestions.length; j++)
            {
                if (suggestions[j].indexOf(inputField.text.toLowerCase()) == 0)
                {
                    var term:TextField = new TextField();
                    term.width = 300;
                    term.height = 20;
                    term.x = 70;
                    term.y = (20 * suggested.length) + 314;
                    term.border = true;
                    term.borderColor = 0x353535;
                    term.background = true;
                    term.backgroundColor = 0xFF9900;
                    term.textColor = 0x4C311D;
                    term.defaultTextFormat = format;

                    term.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, useWord);
                    term.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, hover);
                    term.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, out);
                    term.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, tellMe);

                    addChild(term);
                    textfields.push(term);

                    suggested.push(suggestions[j]);

                    term.text = suggestions[j];
                }

            }

            if (inputField.length == 0)
            {
                suggested = [];

                for (var k:int = 0; k < textfields.length; k++)
                {
                    removeChild(textfields[k]);
                }

                textfields = [];
            }

            if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN && currentSelection < textfields.length-1)
            {
                currentSelection++;
                textfields[currentSelection].textColor = 0x4C311D;
            }

            if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP && currentSelection > 0)
            {
                currentSelection--;
                textfields[currentSelection].textColor = 0x4C311D;
            }

            if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.ENTER)
            {
                inputField.text = textfields[currentSelection].text;

                suggested = [];

                for (var l:int = 0; l < textfields.length; l++)
                {
                    removeChild(textfields[l]);
                }

                textfields = [];
                currentSelection = 0;
            }
        }

         function useWord(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            inputField.text = e.target.text;

            suggested = [];

            for (var i:int = 0; i < textfields.length; i++)
            {
                removeChild(textfields[i]);
            }

            textfields = [];
        }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Change the condition from:

```
suggestions[j].indexOf(inputField.text.toLowerCase()) == 0
```

to

```
suggestions[j].indexOf(inputField.text.toLowerCase()) != -1
```